# Add Percentage display to makefile output

Tags: c, makefile, percentage

My current Makefile is working perfectly, but when it is compiling it hasn't a beatiful ouput. How can I add a output with percentage?

```
EXEC = hawk
SOURCES = $(wildcard src/collections/*.c src/compiler/*.c src/*.c)
OBJECTS = $(SOURCES:.c=.o)
CFLAGS = -Wall -O3 -Isrc/include/
BINDIR = build/bin
BUILDDIR = build
BUILDOBJ = $(addprefix build/, $(OBJECTS))

all: dir $(EXEC)

$(EXEC): $(OBJECTS)
    echo $(SOURCES)
    echo $(OBJECTS)
    gcc  $(BUILDOBJ) $(CFLAGS) -o $(BINDIR)/$(EXEC)
    @cp build/bin/hawk .

$(OBJECTS): %.o : %.c
    gcc -c $(CFLAGS) $< -o $(BUILDDIR)/$@

clean:
    -rm -rf build/*

dir:
    @mkdir -p build
    @mkdir -p build/bin
    @mkdir -p build/src
    @mkdir -p build/src/compiler
    @mkdir -p build/src/collections
```

Comment: Do you mean a "progress bar"?

Comment: Something like ```[1%] Building C Object main.c``` Is used quite common, many uses this

Comment: That's actually feature of CMake and has nothing to do with Make or its Makefile syntax at all.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a misunderstanding about the behavior of a tool and doesn't have a viable code solution in the context presented.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What's the purpose? It would add complexity to the Makefile to make it accurate. Considering files that are NOT compiled (because they are up to date) and parallel compilation (think `make -j`) will not make it easier to implement. If you wish a CMake-style output, just use CMake - they generate progress with a quite complicated bunch of recursive Makefiles and temporary files.

In my opinion adding percentage output is not worth the complexity. To find out what the progress is I would just define objects in alphabetical order like `OBJECTS := $(sort $(SOURCES:.c=.o))`, so one would guess how far the compilation is by looking at the output file name.

Comment: I don't necessarily disagree, but `one would guess how far the compilation is by looking at the output file name` is equally as bad suggestion as implementing progress bar in Makefile when CMake exists and does it all for you.

Comment: It does and that was actually my point: if one wants CMake's output, just use CMake. Personally I have never had a need for a percentage output in a `make` call and I found out painfully how complicated it is in CMake (which can also be non-consistent in a parallel make invocation).

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that CMake did that, well then my question is answeree

Answer (score 0):

Generally you can't. But your makefile is very simple allowing you to do something.

You know all the compilation units since you have them in `OBJECTS`. The objects will be compiled in the other they appear in the prerequisites of `$(EXEC): $(OBJECTS)`. So one simple thing you could to is to add an output to the pattern rule that compiles those objects: `$(OBJECTS): %.o : %.c`. Check how far down into `$(OBJECTS)` the current target `$@` is, convert that into a percentage and print it.

Comment: Do you have an example?

Comment: Sorry, no. Most of my projects are more complex and don't have such a simple list of all object files so a % based on that wouldn't be possible for me.